# How to use CDN for packages in vite

Tags: reactjs, express, optimization, vite, core-web-vitals

In my app express server is serving whole dist build of vite in one go. Then that navigate to different pages within and get data from backend at same host. I want to use cdn for my packages in vite because side of build is 22MB now.

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
        '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
 //other packages
      ],
    },
  },
  // Define CDN links for the specified dependencies
  // Note: Make sure to use the correct version number
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
      '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
      //other packages
    ],
    entries: {
      '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@6.4.0/index.min.js',
      '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@6.4.0/index.min.js
//other links
    },
  },
})
```

this is my vite.config.js getting error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Any other advice for serving site or optiomization is also appreciated.